# Multiline Variables

Tags: batch-file, command-line, netsh

I activate firewalls frequently at my job and most of the time I'm on a laptop.  It's a pain for me to use the top row of numbers because I'm used to a full keyboard layout.  Going into the network adapter properties multiple times and changing the static IP address is no fun.  I didn't just want to make a script that would be used on my computer. I wanted our other technicians to have access a use for it too.  A script that's bullet proof if you will.  I just need help with one section of the code and I've got the rest.
I would like to echo the Net adapter interfaces and give the user an option of what adapter to modify before giving modification options.

I don't know if it's even possible, but this is what I would like the print to look on the user end:

NIC1

NIC2

NIC3

Choose your NIC:

Is anything like that even possible?  Any input would be appreciated.

**SUMMARY:**
Query and print all adapters appending a numerical value to each.
User inputs the value associated with the adapter.
This dumps the Interface name into a variable. I take it from there.

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=3 tokens=1-4 delims= " %%a in ('netsh interface show interface') do (
   @echo %%d    %%b   %%a
)
```

This will display the information I want, but now how I want it.
Is there a way to make each line displayed a variable unto its self?

Ex. Instead of each variable (%%a,%%b,%%c,%%d) displaying all the lines in a token, is there a way to display a single line per token per variable?
Then the user could input the assigned variable of that specific line to specify which network adapter would be modified by the rest of the script.

Comment: Parse the output of the `NETSH` command. `netsh interface show interface`

Comment: Please review your question with more details on inputs given and results wanted. Your question is too vauge and there is a lot of unnecessary explanation on unimportant subjects.

Comment: I added a summary to help with my wandering.

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you, I'm sorry if it came across that way.  I'm really just looking for some direction. Is there even a method for doing what I'm asking (in batch)? Squashman suggested parsing the output, but that's a little vague (much like my question).  If someone could even suggest what type of command to use, I could run with it.  I just need a starting point.

Comment: to parse the output of a command, use [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html), for example `for /f "skip=2 tokens=4" %%a in ('netsh interface show interface') do @echo %%a`

Comment: Thanks @Stephan, that got me much closer. This is what I have so far:
`for /f "skip=3 tokens=1-4 delims= " %%a in ('netsh interface show interface') do (
   @echo %%d %%b %%a
)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a counter to the loop to get an index, you can choose later
and set a variable for every interface.

The `for /l` sets the valid options for `choice` depending on available adapters.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
for /f "skip=3 tokens=1-4 delims= " %%a in ('netsh interface show interface') do (
   set /a count+=1
   set interface[!count!]=%%d    %%b   %%a
   @echo !count!  %%d    %%b   %%a
)
for /l %%i in (1,1,%count%) do set number=!number!%%i
choice /c %number%  /m "type index number"
set index=%errorlevel%
echo you choosed adapter %index%: !interface[%index%]!
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I had no idea about the counter.